# Express Query object undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I have an object **postData** which comes to the controller in form of query when I console log the object it has data:-

```
console.log("data:- ", req.query.postData);
```

**console output:-**

```
data:- {
         "property1":"value1",
         "property2":"value2",
         "property3":"value3",
         "property4":"value4"
       }
```

**But when trying to restructure individual property:-**

```
const {property1,property2,property3,property4} = req.query.postData;
```

```
console.log(property1);
console.log(property2);
console.log(property3);
console.log(property4);
```

**console output:-**

It is `undefined` in console log

Comment: can you pls add the `console.log` you are trying to print in the question

Comment: @Ashishssoni check the edit please.

Comment: can you pls check `console.log("data:- ", typeof(req.query.postData));`, might be a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postData is just a string. You need to convert it to an object with JSON.parse()

```
const {property1,property2,property3,property4} = JSON.parse(req.query.postData);
```

I don't think passing JSON in the query string is really a good idea, though.

** instead, you could send it in the request body.

Or, for the query string use
`?property1=value1&property2=value2&property3=value3&property4=value4`

Comment: what would you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the data you are getting is a type string not an object, you need to parse the string first then destructure it.

```
const {property1,property2,property3,property4} = JSON.parse(req.query.postData)
```

In general, req.query is a string not an object. I suggest you to convert your request from `GET` to `POST` and obtain these data from `req.body` instead of `req.query`, it will be much simpler and easy also a much preferred way.

Comment: yes, it was a string. Thanks for helping